# How do I programmatically add and fill a field to taxonomy terms of a specific vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I want to programmatically do two things:

1. Replace the default multiline Description field of taxonomy term
   with my own, plain text, single line field. I mean - to *visually*
   replace - I understand this is an entity property and all I can do
   is to hide it and create another, plain text field.
2. Populate the vocabulary through `taxonomy_term_save()` - putting the description strings into the newly created field.

Would anyone be kind and provide a skeleton of code to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is really two questions.

For the first, I would use `hook_taxonomy_term_view` to alter `$build['description']['#markup']`, like so:

```
function custom_taxonomy_term_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['description']['#markup'] .= '<p> And this is more stuff.<p>';
}
```

For the second, [`taxonomy_term_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) can take a description field as described on the API docs page.